# How can I run node.js server(application) between two different computers?

Tags: node.js, server

I have a node.js application. This application provides video communication. How can I this application between two different computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `local server` the other computer can access your IP if both the systems are sharing a common network.
If both of the computers are connected to a common router, you can hit the local server of one system through other system by simply hitting its IP.